# The Community Ads Stats page is still using the old ad dimensions

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, advertising

The [Community Promotion Ad Statics page](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/6024) is still using the old Community Ad dimensions, which makes the images in it squashed.

> [image: squished ad images]

Comment: So, I'd modify the images, but I don't know what the final dimensions should be. Any help, there?

Comment: @Smurfton The ads themselves are fine. We don't need to do anything. They're just being squashed into a box that's not the right size.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that it was to do with that thing I've been seeing about the sidebar becoming uniform across sites

Comment: @Smurfton It is! The sidebar is now wider, so our ads are wider. But the image slots in our ad stats page are using the not-wider dimensions, so the ads get squashed narrower to fit in.

Comment: Please see this discussion: http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/q/2442/198 - it is intentional and known at the moment.

Comment: @Marc: Given that this was fixed briefly, [but the fix was reverted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273089/stats-page-squishes-ads-to-the-old-220px-width/273279#273279), this request probably should be marked [meta-tag:status-planned]. I expect we'll probably see a proper fix in six to eight weeks or so. ;) In the mean time, I have a [user script](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) that fixes this issue (among other things).